# A infinite animation on button makes it unclickable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

(Swift) 
I recently noticed a button on my viewController was not clickable because of the animation that is infinitely assigned to it. However, I really need to be able to click that button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.startGradientFunction()

}

 // Function that changes colors over time
func startGradientFunction() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "66B8FF")
        self.readyBtn.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "3F86C3")
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "57FFC4")
            self.readyBtn.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "20CD91")
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "9C49FF")
                    self.readyBtn.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "7E3BCD")

                }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

                    self.startGradientFunction()

                })

            })

        })
}
```

How can I make it selectable again?
I would be glad to know someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add user interaction to your animation options:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions/1622440-allowuserinteraction

(But you should also fix your way of doing a repeating animation so that you don’t recurse infinitely.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll check it. Could you briefly tell me how could I fix the way I repeat the animation please?

Comment: Make a key frame animation and use the repeat option. Basically your whole issue is that you are not using any animation options.